# How can I map one string to another string in C?

Tags: c

Sorry for the bad title, I can't think of a better way to word it.

Suppose I have multiple #defines in my program. In this case:

```
#define HBLK "\e[0;90m"
#define HRED "\e[0;91m"
#define HGRN "\e[0;92m"
#define HYEL "\e[0;93m"
#define HBLU "\e[0;94m"
#define HMAG "\e[0;95m"
#define HCYN "\e[0;96m"
#define HWHT "\e[0;97m"
```

Now, suppose I have a string `"x"`, which is equal to `"HBLU"`, which is a #define from earlier. How would I go about getting C to return `"\e[0;94m"` (what HBLU is defined to) rather than `"HBLU"`?

Comment: Try this - `if (strcmp (x, "HBLU") == 0) return HBLU;`

Comment: C pretty much won't ever return the name of a macro. That's the whole point of preprocessing. Show us what the actual problem is

Comment: That would work, but since I have a define for basically every Unix escape code (much more than listed in the post), is there a way where I don't have to write an if statement for each #define?

Comment: `where I don't have to write an if statement for each #define?` `struct { const char *code; const char *res; } arr[] = { {"HBLU", HBLU}, .... }; for (..) { if (strcmp(x, arr[i].code) return arr[i].res; }`. You could abuse macros `#define _(x, c) if(!strcmp(x, #c)) return c;` `_(x, HBLU);`

Answer (score 1):

Use a series of string-comparisons.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define HBLK "\e[0;90m"
#define HRED "\e[0;91m"
#define HGRN "\e[0;92m"
#define HYEL "\e[0;93m"
#define HBLU "\e[0;94m"
#define HMAG "\e[0;95m"
#define HCYN "\e[0;96m"
#define HWHT "\e[0;97m"

const char * decode(const char *const input)
{
    if (strcmp(input, "HBLK") == 0) return HBLK;
    if (strcmp(input, "HRED") == 0) return HRED;
    if (strcmp(input, "HGRN") == 0) return HGRN;
    if (strcmp(input, "HYEL") == 0) return HYEL;
    if (strcmp(input, "HBLU") == 0) return HBLU;
    if (strcmp(input, "HMAG") == 0) return HMAG;
    if (strcmp(input, "HCYN") == 0) return HCYN;
    if (strcmp(input, "HWHT") == 0) return HWHT;

    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    char* input = "HBLU";
    const char* output = decode(input);

    printf("The result is %s\n", output);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to make a list of key-value mappings, like a primitive dictionary.

Combined with a little pre-processor magic, and its pretty straightforward:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define HBLK "\e[0;90m"
#define HRED "\e[0;91m"
#define HGRN "\e[0;92m"
#define HYEL "\e[0;93m"
#define HBLU "\e[0;94m"
#define HMAG "\e[0;95m"
#define HCYN "\e[0;96m"
#define HWHT "\e[0;97m"

typedef struct
{
    const char *const key;
    const char *const value;
} KVString_t;
#define ENTRY(x) { #x, x }
#define array_sz(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a))

const char * decode(const char *const input)
{
    KVString_t list[] = {
        ENTRY(HBLK), ENTRY(HRED), ENTRY(HGRN), ENTRY(HYEL),
        ENTRY(HBLU), ENTRY(HMAG), ENTRY(HCYN), ENTRY(HWHT),
    };

    for(int i=0; i<array_sz(list); ++i)
    {
        if (strcmp(input, list[i].key) == 0)
        {
            return list[i].value;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    char* input = "HBLU";
    const char* output = decode(input);

    printf("The result is %s\n", output);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
const char *decode(const char *code) {
   const char *control_seq = NULL;
   if (*(code++) == 'H') {
      switch (*(code++)) {
         case 'B': if (strcmp(code, "LK") == 0) control_seq = HBLK;
              else if (strcmp(code, "LU") == 0) control_seq = HBLU; break;
         case 'C': if (strcmp(code, "YN") == 0) control_seq = HCYN; break;
         case 'G': if (strcmp(code, "RN") == 0) control_seq = HGRN; break;
         case 'M': if (strcmp(code, "AG") == 0) control_seq = HMAG; break;
         case 'R': if (strcmp(code, "ED") == 0) control_seq = HRED; break;
         case 'W': if (strcmp(code, "HT") == 0) control_seq = HWHT; break;
         case 'Y': if (strcmp(code, "EL") == 0) control_seq = HYEL; break;
      }
   }

   return control_seq;
}
```